# Should I be considering income bracket when establishing how much I owe for taxes when selling stocks?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Bought some TSLA back in 2015 - 600 shares. I made more than ten times the amount of money. I usually am a believer in holding stuff hence most of my investments are in a roth ira, a 401k and a rollover so I rarely sell stocks.

What percentage needs to go to the irs when I sell this stock?  Is keeping aside at least 20-25% strictly to pay for taxes a suitable amount?

I’ve read some sites say 10, 15, or 20%. Maybe they are basing this on my income. For what its worth I make below 200k yearly. The stock is from a brokerage account through Fidelity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your regular tax bracket will affect how much capital gains tax you owe.

It depends on the exact size of your capital gain (rough calculation says about $400k) and the amount of your other income. But the long-term capitals gains tax brackets are 0%, 15%, and 20%. There is also an additional 3.8% Net Investment Income Tax (NIIT) that applies to investment income above $200k ($250k for married filing jointly), so effectively the brackets are 0%, 15%, 18.8%, and 23.8%. You are almost certainly above the 0% bracket due to your regular income. Some of your gain will probably fall into each of the 3 higher brackets. If you keep 20% of the gain for taxes, that should cover your federal liability; 25% if you want to be sure you save more than you need to. However, don't forget state income taxes--most states tax capital gains like regular income.

For 2021, assuming married filing jointly with no dependents and an AGI (before capital gain) of $175k and the standard deduction ($25,100), you have a taxable income of $149,900. This gives a federal tax of $24,475. Adding a $400k long-term capital gain, you add $62,415 of capital gains tax, plus another $12,350 in NIIT, for a total of $99,240 in federal tax. The excess $74,765 from the capital gain comes out to 18.7% of the capital gain.

Comment: Married filing jointly, agi is 175k

Comment: God I hate taxes...